# Mdl tabs "is-active" class is not getting applied by Angular2 [ngClass]

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

I have created two plunker samples.In the first i tried to apply a class by name active and it applied and here is the demo for it-http://plnkr.co/edit/0txN0C14GPl0ljrpsDlr?p=preview
But when i try to apply "is-active" class it is not applying.why is that so? Here is the plunker demo for it-http://plnkr.co/edit/oNRL4Rc6lmjmaLGXX54H?p=preview

```
 <a href="#starks-panel" id="first" class="mdl-tabs__tab"  [ngClass]="{ is-active: isOn}">Starks</a>
```

Somebody have a look at this code and guide me to correct the mistake

Comment: It's a js object. If you want to use dash in a key you have to wrap the key in ''.
`[ngClass]="{ 'is-active': isOn}"`
should work.

Comment: Thanks bro...it is working

Comment: how about accepting the answer :)

Comment: @kit  
Bro you are really awesome...Actually I got one more problem...I am trying to place a tab inside another tab...the parent tab is operating properly but if i click the child tab it disappears...I tried to run the component handler agian but i didnt get...I have made a plunker sample and here it is->http://plnkr.co/edit/b0ZAI78iEETkGyNIlzSO?p=preview

Comment: check this out https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1173

Answer (score 0):

The `ngClass` was removed and you have to use the brackets binding syntax in the `class` attribute. The resulting code will be something like:

```
<a href="#starks-panel" id="first" class="mdl-tabs__tab"  [class.is-active]="isOn">Starks</a
```